# Can i bind an the datasource Index in a repeater/grid

Tags: indexing, repeater, data-binding

I have a repeater.. and in my repeater i have a link that fires some JS.

I would like to pass the itemIndex of the datasource in the JS.

Is there some way to do this without using OnItemBound or OnItemCreated??

like..

```
<a href="#" onclick="dosomestuff(<%# this.item.index %>); return false;">Add Stuff</a>
```

i know the syntax is completely wrong but hopefully you get the idea.. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<%# Container.ItemIndex %>
```

Comment: How awesome is that? Thanks SLaks!